# Show the text that is between <a> tags on a:hover background

Tags: html, css, hover

Currently when i'm hovering over an image i'm getting the colored background with 0.2 opacity but i'm stuck right now.

I want the text to be displayed in the middle of the hovered color.

It's just sitting beneath the image right now in the background.

EDITED --> Link to JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K7C95/1/

```
<div class="first-portfolio-item">
     <a href="#contact"><img src="img/portfolio-item-one.jpg" />
         <span class="small-text">This image is used as an example</span>
     </a>
     </div>

img{
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
   }

a{

    &:hover{

    display: block;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;

    font-size: 10px;
    color: white;

        opacity: 0.2;
    filter:alpha(opacity=20);   

        }   
    }

.first-portfolio-item{
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 600px;
    float: left;

        &:hover{
            display: block;
            background-color:#47b73b; 
               }
        }
```

Comment: Do you have a JSFiddle so we can see it?

Comment: Here is the JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K7C95/1/

Comment: This is a position issue. You would need to add `position:relative` to the anchor tag then `position:absolute` to the span then tweak the dimensions and position values to suit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `span` is a child of the `a` tags you need to add position:relative to the anchor tag then position:absolute to the span then tweak the dimensions and position values to suit

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/K7C95/8/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="first-portfolio-item">
     <a href="#contact"><img src="http://cdn.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/l-Wittle-puppy-yawning.jpg" />
         <span class="small-text">This image is used as an example</span>
     </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.first-portfolio-item{
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 600px;
    float: left;
}

a > img {
    width: 100%; 
}
a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
a:hover{
    font-size: 10px;
    color: white;
 }


a:hover img{
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter:alpha(opacity=20);   
    }

.first-portfolio-item a > span.smalltext {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 600px;;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your span class has no styling to position it.

One method is to use absolute positioning on your image with your span class of small_text the same.

This way your wrapping div for the image will hold it in relative place, 
Then the text can be positioned accordingly.

You should add something like

```
.small-text{
 position:aboslute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
}
```

Extend your img wrapper to do the same and you have a result.

http://jsfiddle.net/jXQ83/

Only an extremely brief look at this but it should give you an idea.